# Numerical Optimization Methods

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am curious if any one has comments on "specific characteristics" of a problem that will deem it to be best solved by a specific optimization method such as `SimulatedAnnealing`, `Random Search`, or `Diferential Evolution`, etc.

**Edit**: I am familiar with the majority of the `Mathematica` resources which has some useful comments such as:`Random search` requires that the objective function be locally continuous, `DifferentialEvolution` is more suitable for discrete optimization problems since it needs a large gene pool, etc. I wanted a discussion expanding that knowledge based on peoples' experience on when they found one method to be more beneficial than other based on the problem characteristics such as size of solution space, non-linearity, processing speed(time), rate of convergence (iterations), etc.

Ps. Thanks for the resources.

Comment: If you haven't seen [this page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html) yet, it might be wroth a read.

Comment: Also [this](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/4311/) and this [other](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/4035/) contain useful information. This [one too](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/4035/) perhaps.

Comment: @Daniel The 2nd and 3rd link you posted are identical.

Comment: This seems like it should be a community-wiki question that ought to have the standard banner warning, "We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context..."  E.g. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18  (Also, the site's format is Q&A, not discussion.)

Comment: @Michael, Thanks for your suggestion. I am new to this website and wondering if you could help me doing what you are suggesting.

Comment: If you edit an **answer**, there is a community wiki checkbox.  I can't find how to make a question CW.  See these [links](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=wiki) for more info about CW.  You should note that on CW posts reputation points are not earned.  Perhaps someone who knows how to do it will see this and comment.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for spotting that. I had intended it to be [this 2005 Tech Conference item](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/5798/)

Answer (score 10):

Collecting some links to useful resources from the comments:

- The documentation [has a section on global optimization](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html) which has a short section devoted to each method.
- Presentation about `NMinimize` available on the Wolfram Library Archive:

  1. [Numerical Optimization in Mathematica: An Insider's View of `NMinimize`](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/4311/)
  2. [`` NumericalMath`NMinimize ``: A New Standard Package for Global Optimization](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/4035/)
  3. [Numerical Optimization](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/5798/)

Answer (score 2):

[Mathematica Learning Center](https://www.wolfram.com/support/learn/) has a nice tutorial about [Constrained Optimization](https://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/ConstrainedOptimization/ConstrainedOptimization.pdf) and [Unconstrained Optimization](http://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/UnconstrainedOptimization/UnconstrainedOptimization.pdf) available in ebook format (PDF).

You can find more resources in the learning center if you search for [`"numerical optimization"`](http://support.wolfram.com/search/?query=numerical%20optimization).