# How to speed up optimization?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Finding a quadratic polynomial of the best approximation in $L$-metrics to $\sin(x)$ on $[0,5]$, I execute

```
f[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[RealAbs[Sin[x] - a*x^2 - b*x - c], {x, 0, 5}]; 
NMinimize[{Evaluate[f[a, b, c]],   RealAbs[a] <= 20 && RealAbs[b] <= 20 && RealAbs[c] <= 20}, {a, b, c},
AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5] // Timing
```

> `{3923.94, {0.945758, {a -> -0.22899, b -> 0.700517, c -> 0.278367}}}`

As we see

```
Plot[{Sin[x], a*x^2 + b*x + c /. {a -> -0.22898986824771952, 
b -> 0.7005170433410821, c -> 0.27836651693875075}}, {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

, the result is satisfactory, but it takes a lot of time. How to speed up that execution and similar ones (say, with dozen variables)? I don't find out an answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43000/numerical-optimization-methods).

Comment: `F[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[(Sin[x] - a*x^2 - b*x - c)^2, {x, 0, 5}];
sol = NMinimize[{F[a, b, c], 
   a^2 <= 20^2 && b^2 <= 20^2 && c^2 <= 20^2}, {a, b, c}]`

Comment: @cvgmt: Thank you. This is another metrics ($L^2$, not $L$) so the result (with timing) `{49.0156, {0.259964, {a -> -0.186771, b -> 0.533721, c -> 0.365393}}}` differs .

Comment: for `L^2` metrics: `f[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[(Sin[x] - a*x^2 - b*x - c)^2, {x, 0, 5}];
NMinimize[{Evaluate[f[a, b, c]]}, {a, b, c}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 5, Method -> "NelderMead"] // Timing` only **2**
 second.

Comment: Can use `FindMinimum` with starting values given by the parabola that is 0 at  0 and `Pi` and 1 at `Pi/2`. `In[96]:= Timing[
 FindMinimum[f[a, b, c], {a, -4/Pi^2}, {b, 4/Pi}, {c, 0}]]

During evaluation of In[96]:= FindMinimum::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within the tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

Out[96]= {15.1358, {0.945758, {a -> -0.22899, b -> 0.700517, 
   c -> 0.278367}}}`

Comment: why do you have to use `NIntegrate`? is this not enough? `x = Table[i, {i, 0, 5, 0.05}];` `NMinimize[{Sqrt[Total@Power[Abs[(Sin[x] - a*x^2 - b*x - c)], 2]], 
   RealAbs[a] <= 20 && RealAbs[b] <= 20 && RealAbs[c] <= 20}, {a, b, 
   c}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5] // Timing`

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit *out there*, but you can actually do this using the neural network facilities which opens up the possibility to use a GPU:

```
Remove["Global`*"];

f = Sin[#] &; (* Our target *)
g = {1, #, #^2} &; (* various functions to sum with learned weights to approximate f. *)

net = NetGraph[{
    FunctionLayer[g, "Input" -> "Real", "Output" -> Length[g[0]]],
    NetArrayLayer["Output" -> Length[g[0]]],
    DotLayer[],
    FunctionLayer[-f[#] &],
    TotalLayer[],
    FunctionLayer[RealAbs]}, {NetPort["Input1"] -> 1, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 
    NetPort["Input1"] -> 4, 4 -> 5, 3 -> 5, 5 -> 6}];
net = NetInitialize[net];
training = # -> 0 & /@ RandomReal[{0, 5}, 100000];
net = NetTrain[net, training, TargetDevice -> "GPU", BatchSize -> 256];
coeffs = NetExtract[net, 2][];
Plot[{f[x], coeffs . g[x]}, {x, 0, 5}]
```

The resulting coefficients `coeffs` are the optimized `{c,b,a}` in your quadratic, so the polynomial is given by the dot product `coeffs . {1, x, x^2}`
You may wonder where the integration has gone. Well I believe the gradients are accumulated over the whole batch, so the overall change to the parameters is based on evaluation at many random points in the domain, not just one at a time. In this way, the effect of batching is similar to Monte Carlo integrating the loss first, then updating the parameters so they produce a lower loss for the overall batch.

---

You could also consider not doing the integration, but instead sampling at random points. This cuts down the time by a lot, and decreases the accuracy. It is somewhat similar to the neural method above, but uses global optimization instead and only requires a small adjustment to your code:

```
f[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] :=
 Sum[RealAbs[Sin[x] - a*x^2 - b*x - c], {x, RandomReal[{0, 5}, 500]}, 
  Method -> "Procedural"]
{err, sol} = 
 Quiet[NMinimize[{Evaluate[f[a, b, c]], 
    RealAbs[a] <= 20 && RealAbs[b] <= 20 && RealAbs[c] <= 20}, {a, b, 
    c}, MaxIterations -> 100, 
   Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "PostProcess" -> False}],
  NMinimize::cvmit]
```

Extending to other norms is easy too, just define `f` like this, where p is a number, or $\infty$ for the $L_\infty$ max norm:

```
f[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] :=
 Norm[Sin[#] - a*#^2 - b*# - c & /@ 
   RandomReal[{0, 5}, 500], p]
```

Comment: Thank you for your very interesting answer. Unfortunately, the code does not work on my comp, returning "NetTrain::mxgpulibdwnld: TargetDevice -> "GPU" requires additional libraries to be installed. Automatic download is starting. Please check the list of supported GPU compute capabilities in the documentation page for TargetDevice, and ensure an NVIDIA GPU with supported compute capability is installed. Also ensure that an NVIDIA driver of version 511.65 or higher is installed" and so on. What is your result for `a,b,c`? How much time does it take?

Comment: When you get that message the first time, you need to wait for it to download all the libraries (assuming you have a supported GPU), then quit mathematica completely, and restart, but after that it should work. You can use CPU instead otherwise. It takes around 20s to 40s. I get coeffs a,b,c as {0.361709, 0.54002, -0.186718} which looks fairly close to your result. @user64494

Comment: My weak comp is not equipped in  an NVIDIA card at all. Hope I'm clear.

Comment: You can use `TargetDevice->"CPU"`, however I've also added an alternative approach above which similarly relies on random sampling to cut down the evaluations. @user64494

Comment: With `TargetDevice->"CPU"` I obtain "LibraryFunction::load: The library C:\Users\Maryan\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Paclets\Repository\MXNetResources-WIN64-13.3.20\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\zlibwapi.dll cannot be loaded."

Comment: Your second approach is fast, but unprecise. Even `f[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
 Sum[RealAbs[Sin[x] - a*x^2 - b*x - c], {x, 
   RandomReal[{0, 5}, 10000]}, Method -> "Procedural"]
NMinimize[{Evaluate[f[a, b, c]], 
   RealAbs[a] <= 20 && RealAbs[b] <= 20 && RealAbs[c] <= 20}, {a, b, 
   c}, MaxIterations -> 500, 
  Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", 
    "PostProcess" -> False}] // Timing` results in `{117.625, {1905.93, {a -> -0.239461, b -> 0.740007, c -> 0.257833}}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `Orthogonalize` for this? This finds an orthogonal basis for the powers of x over [0,5] and then projects `Sin` onto it to find the coefficients in that basis. The result looks the same and it's nearly instantaneous for the quadratic case:

```
innerProduct[f_, g_] := Integrate[f g, {x, 0, 5}]
basis = Orthogonalize[Table[x^k, {k, 0, 2}], innerProduct];
result = 
 Sum[Projection[Sin[x], basis[[i]], innerProduct], {i, 
   Length[basis]}]
Plot[{result, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

You get exact coefficients:

```
CoefficientList[result, x]

(* {2/5 Sin[5/2]^2 + 3/25 (5 + 5 Cos[5] - 2 Sin[5]) + 
  1/25 (13 - 13 Cos[5] + 30 Sin[5]), -(6/
    125) (5 + 5 Cos[5] - 2 Sin[5]) - 
  6/125 (13 - 13 Cos[5] + 30 Sin[5]), 
 6/625 (13 - 13 Cos[5] + 30 Sin[5])} *)

(* {0.365393, 0.533721, -0.186771} *)
```

---

This is $L_2$ only though, and unfortunately I don't think you can define an inner product with an $L_1$ norm as it would violate the parallelogram law.

Comment: +1. Many thanks from me to you for your interest to the question and your work.  All that works well in $L^2$, but I am interested in the general case $L^p, p \ge 1$.

Comment: This is a touchstone for global optimization which is slow in the case of many variables, say dozen.